# Nullpointer Exception on new setText property of Button for no reason

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null

This is just the code for one activity in my app and what it basically does is, depending on the location it provides a list of people to contact in case of an emergency. However, i recently received some new data to be added to the app and now i had to add a few more buttons to the layout (Initially there were only 2 buttons) and for some reason i'm getting a nullpointer exception on the new buttons that i've added. It makes no sense as to why im getting such an exception because i believe i have initialized the buttons properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Contacts.java

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Contacts extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button bt1;
    Button bt2;
    Button bt3;
    Button bt4;
    Button bt5;
    Button bt6;

    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t5;
    TextView t6;

    private String num1;
    private String num2;
    private String num3;
    private String num4;
    private String num5;
    private String num6;
   // RelativeLayout myLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String branch = extras.getString("branch");
        String level = extras.getString("level");
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button1);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button2);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button3);
        bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button4);
        bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button5);
        bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button6);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        if(branch.contentEquals("Hoody") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Javaji P");
            bt2.setText("H S Rao");
            bt3.setText("Sunil KB");
            bt4.setText("K Kishor");
            bt5.setText("Vincent");
            bt6.setText("Sreenivas K");
            num1 = "+919845956099";
            num2 = "+919686198661";
            num3 = "+919880141599";
            num4 = "+919880185109";
            num5 = "+919844303344";
            num6 = "+919880598205";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Hoody") && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           // t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  t2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           /// t3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  t4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         //   t6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "08022979333";
        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Hoody") && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("B S Lokeshwaran(Head-Admin)");
            bt2.setText("Philip Mammen(Head-HR)");
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         //   t2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    t6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919741144114";
            num2 = "+919880141779";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("BTP") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Javaji P");
            bt2.setText("H S Rao");
            bt3.setText("Sunil KB");
            bt4.setText("K Kishor");
            bt5.setText("Roshan");
            bt6.setText("Varghese M");
            num1 = "+919845956099";
            num2 = "+919686198661";
            num3 = "+919880141599";
            num4 = "+919880185109";
            num5 = "+919945729472";
            num6 = "+919880114562";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("BTP") && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "08022984000";
        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("BTP") && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("B S Lokeshwaran(Head-Admin)");
            bt2.setText("Philip Mammen(Head-HR)");
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919741144114";
            num2 = "+919880141779";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("TD") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {

            bt1.setText("Javaji P");
            bt2.setText("H S Rao");
            bt3.setText("Sunil KB");
            bt4.setText("K Kishor");
            bt5.setText("Anitha S");
            bt6.setText("Sreenivas K");
            num1 = "+919845956099";
            num2 = "+919686198661";
            num3 = "+919880141599";
            num4 = "+919880185109";
            num5 = "+919980299033";
            num6 = "+919880598205";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("TD") && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "08022979761";
        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("TD") && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("B S Lokeshwaran(Head-Admin)");
            bt2.setText("Philip Mammen(Head-HR)");
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919741144114";
            num2 = "+919880141779";

        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Neyyar") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge")) || (branch.contentEquals("Leela") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge")) || (branch.contentEquals("Gayathri") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge")))
        {
            bt1.setText("Tony");
            bt2.setText("Jossy Joseph");
            num1 = "+919745818995";
            num2 = "+919961528687";

        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Neyyar")||branch.contentEquals("Leela")|| branch.contentEquals("Gayathri")) && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "04716661000";
        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Neyyar")||branch.contentEquals("Leela")|| branch.contentEquals("Gayathri")) && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Sreekumar.V(Centre Head)");
            bt2.setText("Ajish MJ(Head-HR)");
            num1 = "+919846022266";
            num2 = "+919895806075";

        }

        if(branch.contentEquals("Chennai") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Meeran");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919884515288";


        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Chennai") && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "08022979761";
        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Chennai") && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Jayendran.G(Center Head)");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919840385745";


        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Alpha 1 & 2") || branch.contentEquals("SEZ")) && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Laxman Jadhav");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919689887857";

        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Alpha 1 & 2") || branch.contentEquals("SEZ")) && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bt6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "02066060033";
        }
        if((branch.contentEquals("Alpha 1 & 2") || branch.contentEquals("SEZ")) && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Mr.Vasant Shah(Center Head)");
            bt2.setText("Ms.Simrit Dhindasa(Sr.Executive-HR)");
            num1 = "+919503838082";
            num2 = "+919921183320";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Mumbai") && level.contentEquals("Safety In Charge"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Naveen Dighe");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919821142863";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Mumbai") && level.contentEquals("Emergency Declarer"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Nagarajan(Center Head)");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "+919967723450";

        }
        if(branch.contentEquals("Mumbai") && level.contentEquals("Fire/Accident/Ambulance"))
        {
            bt1.setText("Security");
            bt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            num1 = "0226822145";
        }

    }

    public void launchDialer(String number)
    {
        String numberToDial = "tel:"+number;
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));
    }

    public void onClickbt1(View view)
    {
    launchDialer(num1);
    }

    public void onClickbt2(View view)
    {
        launchDialer(num2);
    }

    public void onClickbt3(View view)
    {
        launchDialer(num3);
    }

    public void onClickbt4(View view)
    {
        launchDialer(num4);
    }

    public void onClickbt5(View view)
    {
        launchDialer(num5);
    }

    public void onClickbt6(View view)
    {
        launchDialer(num6);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contacts, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_contacts.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.prashanth.emergencycontacts.Contacts"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 1"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button1"
        android:onClick="onClickbt1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 2"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClickbt2"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 3"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:onClick="onClickbt3"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 4"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:onClick="onClickbt4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/contact_button3"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 5"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button5"
        android:onClick="onClickbt5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CONTACT 6"
        android:id="@+id/contact_button6"
        android:onClick="onClickbt6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contact_button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Security"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Health &amp; Safety"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Transport"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Maintenance"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Housekeeping"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="IT"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact_button6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat -

```
07-06 22:23:37.574  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.prashanth.emergencycontacts time:14497951
07-06 22:23:37.601  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts I/ViewRootImpl﹕ CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
07-06 22:23:37.637  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f428e3d time:14498015
07-06 22:23:37.662  24510-24528/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa18af280 (ListView) with handle 0xaec2ce40
07-06 22:23:38.413  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.prashanth.emergencycontacts time:14498790
07-06 22:23:38.472  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-06 22:23:38.473  24510-24510/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.prashanth.emergencycontacts, PID: 24510
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prashanth.emergencycontacts/com.prashanth.emergencycontacts.Contacts}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.prashanth.emergencycontacts.Contacts.onCreate(Contacts.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's clearly mentioned the line number in the exception. Did u checked that?

Comment: I checked the line number and the xml files thoroughly and i cant find out why the button points to a null!

Answer (score 2):

The crash logs clearly tell whats going wrong.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.prashanth.emergencycontacts.Contacts.onCreate(Contacts.java:65)
```

You are trying to call `setText()` on a `Button` which is null. It also tells you which line its crashing on.

```
Contacts.onCreate(Contacts.java:65)
```

That means, you need to check for line#65. Line 65 is

```
bt1.setText("Javaji P");
```

ie `bt1` is `null`. But you are finding `bt1` before in the following line

```
bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button1);
```

So that means `bt1` is not present in `activity_contacts.xml` layout, or the id `contact_button1` is wrong.

Please try to understand how the crash logs work, because this is a very basic crash and you should know how to fix it quickly.

Comment: That was the first thing i did. I checked line #65 and i know that i have initialized my buttons properly and that they are present in the xml file. It makes no sense as to why im getting this error as the buttons are present and have been initialized!

Comment: Also line #65 points to  bt3.setText("Sunil KB"); and the app runs properly if i comment the lines of code using all the buttons EXCEPT bt1 and bt2. For some weird reason it shows errors for all the buttons bt3 throught bt6.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file you are referring to existing element IDs with @+id, e.g:

android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_button1"

You should use @+id when creating new ids. Use @id when referring to an already created id, e.g:

android:layout_alignLeft="@id/contact_button1"